# How do I achieve the GMail-like tabbed/decked interface with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gmail

I'm trying to create an interface that's like the right-hand side of what's shown below with jQuery -- tabbed/decked messages with header(subject) and footer.
[image]

Has anyone done something similar with jQuery or can suggest a direction to approach the problem? I've searched on the Web for a while but haven't found a solution that's close enough. I ran across the "[30 jQuery tabs tutorial](http://webdesign14.com/30-useful-jquery-tabs-tutorials/)" but didn't find what I am looking for either.

Thanks in advance for your help. Let me know if I can provide more details on what I'm looking for.

Comment: Doesn't that work like an accordion?

Comment: Accordion only shows one section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic ugly idea:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<scriptsrc="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.thread .head').click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
    return false;
    }).next().hide();
    }); 
</script
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>basic Idea</title>

<style>
  .thread { width: 300px; border: 1px soildl; }
  .thread h2{ background-color: #CCC; margin: 0; border: 1px solid #FFC;}
  .thread div{ background-color:#FDF; border: 1px solid #000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="thread">
    <h2 class="head">The information here</h2>
    <div>
       blah blah blah blah
    </div>
    <h2 class="head">come other information here</h2>
    <div>
       blah blah blah blah Goo Goo Goo
    </div>
    <h2 class="head">hee hee hee</h2>
    <div>
       ho ho ho ho ho
    </div>    
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ekikag/)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to create an accordion.

I highly recommend jQuery Tools - http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/accordion.html